# Switch image to text onClick in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, react-functional-component

I've searched for similar questions but I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to switch from a photo to a text onClick, so that when I click on the photo the text shows, instead of the image. But when I click on the photo I get the error: *"setToggleImage is not a function"*.

I am almost certain I am missing something out but I cannot see it. Here is the code, any help before I go crazy it is greatly appreciated:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import profilePhoto from '../images/_MG_9807.JPG';

const contactInfo = {
    title: 'Contact: ',
    email: 'email: xxx@gmail.com',
    Github:  ' Github: ', 
    linkedin: 'linkedin: ',
};

const ImageContactDetails = () => {
    const [ toggleImage, setToggleImage ] = useState(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='imageContactDetails' onClick={() => setToggleImage(!toggleImage)} > 
                { toggleImage ? <Image id='imageDetails' src={profilePhoto}   alt='professionalprofile' /> : 
                <div>   
                    <h4> {contactInfo.title} </h4>
                    <h5> {contactInfo.email} </h5>
                    <h5> {contactInfo.Github} </h5>
                    <h5> {contactInfo.linkedin} </h5>
                </div>   
                }
            </div>
            <div id='contactInfo'></div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ImageContactDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState()` returns a pair of values in an array, so you should use array destructuring. It should be:

```
const [toggleImage, setToggleImage] = useState(true);
```

Comment: ah! thank you for fixing that. However, after changing it I am still not getting the code to work. It does not show me an error, but it is not changing on click (the alert does work though). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Great, I'm happy to look into your code @AOJ if you can share it. What I can see at the moment is that your `changeToText` should not return anything. I'd probably ditch it entirely and add an inline function to onClick, like `onClick={() => setToggleImage(!toggleImage)}` and render in your `return` conditionally based on the value of `toggleImage`.

Comment: Thank you so much! that actually did the trick I was trying to do. You have no idea how excited I got once it worked. 
I have updated all the code above. It's not really much, that is all I have for it. However I ran into another small issue. after the " : " in the ternary operator I was trying to call several paragraphs and that did not work, so I made that variable "allInformation" to store what I wanted to use and it prints but it is all mashed up together. Any advice on how I could break them in several lines?

Comment: No worries. However, you cannot chuck an array in like that though. React will convert it to a list of text nodes which will be displayed on a single line. You need to add the necessary HTML tags (and I'm pretty sure `h4` is not the right one there. Probably an `ul` + `li` or a `dl` list?)

Comment: Hi Zsolt, I had not a chance to come back and thank you for the advice earlier. 
Actually, I figured out what I was doing wrong on the first place, which was a very basic thing. I had not realised that in react all the returns have to be wrap in one root DOM element where there is more than one element. I thought it was just for the main one. code is updated in case it can help anyone else.

Comment: @AOJ, I'm glad I could help; however, if you think it solved your problem, you can also accept my answer ;)